# What is URL for swagger

Tags: magento-1.9

I've installed magento 1.9 with sample data.

From [swagger Documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/) page, I see that the Base url for swagger must be `/index.php/rest/default`. However, when I visit this link, I get 404 Page not found.

Is swagger there by default in Magento 1.9 ? What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swagger is only available in Magento 2.x. You can check on [devdocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/) site also there is title mentioned

**You can refer the below links:**

> For Magento 1.x API documentation,

[**Soap API documentation**](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/introduction.html)

[**Rest API documentation**](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest-api-index.html)

Comment: Thanks for confirming @pankaj. Can I use swagger by installing manually on magento 1.9?

Comment: I don't have idea about that but I have shared M1 api documentation links